# how can i activate function update

Tags: c#, visual-studio

the problem i have are

> Assets\Scripts\Gunfire.cs(1,1): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'function' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Gunfire.cs(1,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot
>   directly contain members such as fields or methods

the script is

```
function Update
{
    get
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            var;
            { gunsound; }
            AudioSource = GetComponent.AudioSource();
            gunsound.Play();
            GetComponent.Animation > (Play("GunShot"));
        }
    }
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: You may need to go back for some basic C# syntax lessons. `var;` and `{ gunsound;}` are not things I'd expect to see from someone who's had even a few weeks real practice with the language.

Comment: Similar as what @JoelCoehoorn is saying,  `function` is not how you declare a function in C#. I looks like you are trying to implement a `get` on a property of an object. So instead of function, you would want the type of thing being returned. However you  aren't returning anything, so I am guess you probably just want to declare a void method instead of a property with a `get`

Answer (score 0):

`function` is not a C# keyword. It looks like youa re trying to write JavaScript maybe.

C# function syntax is like this:

```
{returnType} {methodName} ({parameters}) { {body} }

int Add (int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

In C# all functions must belong to a class. (This may change in C#9)

You can see an example of this if you create a new C# console app in Visual Studio.